# How to properly use CDialog::Create for Modalless dialogs MFC

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, mfc

I am trying to create a Modalless dialog in my exsisting project. CDialog::Create cause debug assertion. I tried a new Dialog based application and followed the same steps, the dialog gets created without any error.
Also in my exsisiting project I am using MFC as static Library, can this affect the functionality?
really looking forward for any helpful replies
Best Regards

Comment: what kind of a project is your "existing project"? (SDI, MDI or dialog based?) where are you calling `CDialog::Create()`? and what kind of a debug assertion do you get? Please give some code of how you are calling `CDialog::Create()` with parameters

Comment: its dll based project not SDI, MDI, and i am linking it statically

Comment: There is no such thing as a *"dll based project"*. Please update your question with the information requested by Edward. In particular, the complete message of the debug assertion is required (use Ctrl+C on the assertion dialog to copy the text).

Comment: You must show us some code!

Comment: Debug Assertion Failed!

Program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office 14\Outlook.exe
File: f:\dd\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\include\afxwin1.inl
Line:24

Comment: DisconMessage *pdlg=NULL;

    if(!fShowDisconnectionMessage)
    {
    if(pdlg == NULL)
    {
    pdlg = new DisconMessage();

    if(pdlg != NULL)
    {
        
    if(!pdlg->Create(DisconMessage::IDD,(CWnd*)GetDesktopWindow()))
    
    fShowDisconnectionMessage = TRUE;
    
    }
    }
    }

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25285652/edit) the question to include the information posted as comments. Comments have very few formatting options, to make the information readable.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just a stab in the dark given the vagueness and lack of information in the question, but have you created the dialog as a WS_CHILD and not WS_POPUP?